# Error de variables declaradas en un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo este procedimiento que uso para escoger entre un tipo de usuario u otro para una ventana de login, me da error de sintaxis pero no encuentro el fallo en la lógica.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_Login
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@usuario varchar(50),
@password varchar(50),
@id int output,
@inst varchar(10)output
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
@id = (SELECT Id_Usuario FROM Usuarios WHERE CodigoUsuario = @usuario AND Password = @password)
if @id!=-1
begin
    @inst = 'true'
    print 'true'
end
else
begin
    @id =(SELECT  Id_Administrador FROM Administradores WHERE Usuario=@usuario AND Password = @password)
    if @id!=-1
    begin
        @inst =  'false'
        print 'false'
    end
    else
    begin
        @inst =  'none'
        print 'none'
    end
end
END
GO
```

CodigoUsuario y Usuario nunca tienen el mismo nombre

Los errores del procedimiento están en el Insert statements, en @id y @inst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final estas fueron las modificaciones:

```
set @id = (SELECT Id_Usuario FROM Usuarios WHERE CodigoUsuario = @usuario AND Password = @password)
if @id!=-1
begin
    set @inst = 'true'
end
else
begin
    set @id =(SELECT  Id_Administrador FROM Administradores WHERE Usuario=@usuario AND Password = @password)
    if @id!=-1
    begin
        set @inst =  'false'
    end
    else
    begin
        set @inst =  'none'
    end
end
```

Espero que si a alguien le pasa algo parecido, esto le sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Las asignaciones de variables en **SQL SERVER** se hacen mediante la clausula `SET` o bien directamente desde un `SELECT`. En tu caso deberías reemplazar esas intrucciones:

```
@id = (SELECT Id_Usuario FROM Usuarios WHERE CodigoUsuario = @usuario AND Password = @password)
@id = (SELECT  Id_Administrador FROM Administradores WHERE Usuario=@usuario AND Password = @password)
```

por

```
SELECT @id = Id_Usuario FROM Usuarios WHERE CodigoUsuario = @usuario AND Password = @password
SELECT @id = Id_Administrador FROM Administradores WHERE Usuario=@usuario AND Password = @password
```

Y por otro lado, esta asignación `@inst = 'true'` y las otras similares, deberías reemplazarlas por `SET @inst = 'true'` o eventualmente `SELECT @inst = 'true'`

Comment: con SELECT @id=Id_Usuario era como lo tenía al principio. No puse los SET porque cuando hice el procedimiento la primera vez no los había usado y funcionaban.

Answer (score 1):

Para asignar un valor a una variable debes de hacerlo mediante la instrucción SET tal como ya te lo han comentado. Por otro lado, si la subconsulta no recupera filas el valor resultante no será -1 será NULL.

Intenta con el siguiente código:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_Login
@usuario  varchar(50),
@password varchar(50),
@id       int OUTPUT,
@inst     varchar(10) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN    
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @id = (SELECT Id_Usuario FROM Usuarios 
   WHERE CodigoUsuario = @usuario AND [Password] = @password);

IF @id IS NOT NULL SET @inst = 'true';            
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @id = (SELECT Id_Administrador FROM Administradores
      WHERE Usuario = @usuario AND [Password] = @password);

   IF @id IS NOT NULL        
        SET @inst = 'false';            
    ELSE        
        SET @inst = 'none';            
END

PRINT @inst;
END
GO
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final hice una mezcla entre este código y el que tenía originalmente y ya funciona

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es la forma de asignar las varables @id, rueba a cambiar los del select que utilizas para asignar de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  Id_Administrador into @id FROM Administradores WHERE Usuario=@usuario AND Password = @password;
```

Por otra parte, tampoco tengo muy claro la sintaxis del if que utilizas, en la [pagina](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) del manual puedes ver la sintaxis necesaria

Comment: He probado y sigue sin funcionar. Este procedimiento lo creé ayer y funcionaba correctamente, pero me borraron el archivo y ahora no soy capaz de reproducirlo.